# Remove all http://www.example.com but keep http://example.com without www

Tags: seo, subdomain, google-search-console

I changed my URL from `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` expecting some time where Google would update. Also I made redirects in .htaccess from www traffic to non-www traffic.

However I still see est. 2500 links in Google using the www after almost two month and most of them are now outdated links so this means that the user is ending up on the frontpage.

I am considering to request Google to remove all the `http://www.` links to solve the 404 problem.

But is this recommended and how do I do it?

Comment: Did you do 302 or 301 redirects?

Comment: I use 301 with RewriteEngine on

Comment: No, dont remove www, it will remove everything. Make sure the urls are returning a true 404 and if so, just be patient. It can take a while for old urls to be recrawled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your preferred domain in your google webmaster tools account? [image]

Answer (score 0):

No it is not recommended. But you can accelerate the process by submitting a sitemap with the http links to your pages and a recent lastmod date. It will force Google to recrawl these pages and notice the 301 redirects.